# Running Sail for the first time on a new Laravel project, fails with exit code: 127

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu, sails.js

I'm trying to run sail up for the first time, on a virtual machine (Ubuntu).

Here's what I think might be connected to the issue I'm having:

```
8.11.0
fable@KOMPUTER:~/*****$ sudo ./vendor/bin/sail up
[sudo] password for fable:
[+] Running 0/1
 ⠿ laravel.test Error                                                                                 

                                                           
 => ERROR [ 4/11] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip 

------

#7 282.4 invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
#7 282.4 invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
#7 310.6 debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed


#7 431.2 No schema files found: doing nothing.
#7 466.0 update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/automake.1.gz because 
associated file /usr/share/man/man1/automake-1.16.1.gz (of link group automake) doesn't exist
#7 466.0 update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/aclocal.1.gz because 
associated file /usr/share/man/man1/aclocal-1.16.1.gz (of link group automake) doesn't exist

#7 610.7 /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found

failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update: (blablabla): exit code: 127
```

Comment: I think you mean Laravel Sails. The sails.js tag you used is for an MVC Node.js framework https://sailsjs.com